# How to add value in one dataframe to a new column in another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have two DataFrames of different sizes.

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame()
df2 = pd.DataFrame()
df1["id"] = ["A", "A", "B", "B", "C", "C"]
df1["revenue"] = [1, 2, 10, 9, 11, 14]
df2["id"] = ["A", "B", "C"]
df2["revenue"] = [12, 1, 5]
```

[image]
[image]

I want to create a new column in df1 titled revenue_year_1 and fill it with the revenue values in df2 conditional on the id values being equal. So in df1 in both lines where the id is 'A' `revenue_year_1` would be `12`, where the id is 'B' the `revenue_year_1` would be 1 and where the `id` is `C` the `revenue_year_1` would be `5`. In practice I'm doing this on a larger data set where I would not be able to do this by hand.

Desired outcome:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could also `merge` on "id":

```
df1 = df1.merge(df2, on='id', suffixes=('','_year_1'))
```

Output:

```
  id  revenue  revenue_year_1
0  A        1              12
1  A        2              12
2  B       10               1
3  B        9               1
4  C       11               5
5  C       14               5
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `pd.Series.map`, first create a mapping series using set_index on df2:

```
df1['revenue_year_1'] = df1['id'].map(df2.set_index('id')['revenue'])
print(df1)
```

Output:

```
  id  revenue  revenue_year_1
0  A        1              12
1  A        2              12
2  B       10               1
3  B        9               1
4  C       11               5
5  C       14               5
```

Comment: Map in this nearly twice as fast and doing a full table merge.